# How to add new view to Ruby on Rails Spree commerce app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

A very basic question that I cannot seem to solve is how to add a new view to my Ruby on Rails Spree commerce application. What I want to do is have a link next to the Home link in the _main_nav_bar.html.erb and when you click it have displayed an about page at the place where the products are displayed. So:

```
home about       cart
---------------------
things of the HOME page
---------------------
footer
```

Click on about leads to:

```
home about       cart
---------------------
things of the ABOUT page
---------------------
footer
```

In views/shared/_main_nav_bar.html.erb the link I created (based on the home link) looks as follows:

```
<li id="home-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:home), spree.root_path %></li>
<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), spree.about %></li>
```

The AboutController I created looks as follows:

```
module Spree
  class AboutController < Spree::StoreController

    def index

    end
  end
end
```

And finally, in config/routes.rb I added the following code:

```
root :about => 'about#index'
```

When I now try to start the server it just does not work anymore without giving an error message.

Can someone please help me out on this issue? How do I add a view and create a working link that loads in the main div?

EXTRA: routes.rb

```
MyStore::Application.routes.draw do


  mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/'

  Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
     #get 'user/spree_user/logout', :to => "spree/user_sessions#destroy"
  end


  get '/about' => 'spree/about#index'
  get '/contact' => 'spree/contact#index'


end
```

Comment: try: `root :about => 'spree/about#index'` in your routes.rb

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did and it says: 
`ArgumentError
missing :controller
Extracted source (around line #63):
root :about => 'spree/about#index'`

I do have the controller in spree/about_controller.rb which I placed in the post.

Comment: it should be `root :to => 'spree/about#index'`. Sorry.

Comment: Now the code in routes.rb looks like this:

  `root :to => 'home#index'` 
  `root :about => 'spree/about#index'` and it gives the error 
`ArgumentError
Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the :as option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.`

Comment: Dude, you can't have multiple **root** in one application. Either do this: `get '/about' => 'spree/about#index'` for your case.

Comment: Okay seems logical, when I do get it says it cannot find the controller again. Message: `Argumenterror missing :controller
Extracted source (around line #63):
    
root :to => 'home#index'
get :about => 'spree/about#index'`.

Comment: Did you try what I wrote? Does it work?

Comment: I updated the routes.rb with the `get '/about' => 'spree/about#index'` and the server starts again without errors! Thanks! The link does not work though. I have `<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), spree.root_path%></li>`, so naturally it links to `spree.root_path` still? How do I make this link go to /about?

Comment: You're new to spree, I suppose? Do: `get '/about' => 'spree/about#index', :as => :about` in routes.rb and in link(view template): `<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), about_path%></li>`. this should work.

Comment: Yes quite new! :) For now: `about_path is undefined`. Where do I define these variables?

Comment: I am sorry, I am naive. Pardon me. Did you do: `get '/about' => 'spree/about#index', :as => :about` in your **routes.rb**?

Comment: Yes. And now the localhost:3000/about links correctly to the about.html.erb page I made in views/about/index.html.erb. The only issue is how to make the link in the _main_nav_bar.html.erb. Then we are there ;-).

Comment: link: `<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), about_path%></li>` should work. otherwise try with: `spree.about_path` instead of `about_path`

Comment: Still get the `undefined method about_path for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0xc8008d4>` when I do `spree.about_path` or only `about_path`. Do I need to map this `about_path` to /about somewhere?

Comment: Can you post routes.rb file? I am guessing you have `get '/about' ..` with in a block or may be helper isn't being set properly. if not then Do: `rake routes|grep about` in terminal(by cd to your app's directory) and post the output.

Comment: Adder routes.rb to question and output of `rake routes|grep about` is  `about GET /about(.:format)   spree/about#index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do in **routes.rb**:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  get '/about', :to => 'about#index', :as => :about
end
```

or without the `Spree::Core` scope:

```
get '/about', :to => 'spree/about#index', :as => :about
```

Because, you have your **about_controller.rb** i.e. `AboutController` defined inside `Spree` module. And, hence you'll have to reference the **spree** namespace in your route to set it properly.

In your views:

```
<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), spree.about_path %></li>
```

or

```
<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), main_app.about_path %></li>
```

Comment: Well you helped a lot so far, but it is not completely working. I still get the error: `NameError in Spree::Home#index undefined local variable or method about_path in <li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), about_path %></li>`

Comment: If it didn't solve your problem then why you accepted the answer? Well.. idk why `about` isn't working because, `:as => :about` should set two routing helpers:`about_path` and `about_url` for your application. And, I find it weird that you're getting error at about_path..

Comment: Ha you helped me so much so far I thought I give you some credit. ;-)

Comment: See this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes as you can find, for logout, you get logout_path and logout_url. So, I am clueless why it isn't working here. see the update, maybe it helps. :/

Comment: it is an issue with Spree: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064533/adding-routes-to-rails-spree-e-commerce#10215596.

Comment: Oh Okay. So, one work around can be by wrapping it within the spree block. See the update.

Comment: If I use your updated routes.rb code it does work in the sense that the server starts, and that the link is displayed when I hover. But when I click it I get the error: `uninitialized constant Spree::Spree` with a list of the routes underneath. Any ideas?

Comment: please copy and paste the exact code I wrote. you must have had: `get '/about', :to => 'spree/about#index', :as => :about` code inside the Spree::Core block. :(

Comment: I have the correct code. In routes.rb there is the main `MyStore:Application.routes.draw` block and in that block a `Spree::Core::Engine.routes.prepend` block. I am able to visit the site if I place it in the latter block and refresh a few times. But then I get the error when I actually click the link.

Comment: Prefixing the route with main_app worked. As in `<li id="about-link" data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:about), main_app.about_path %></li>`! So now the whole problem is solved! Maybe you can update your answer with this main_app prefix in it and the explanation that "Because you're calling this inside a spree template you need to prefix it with
main_app., like main_app.products_starting_with_path". :-) And thanks a lot for your effort!